# Use median value of array as parameter in query

Tags: jsonata

I want to use the resulting median as the parameter for calculating "larger". How can I do this?

```
{
  "h": {
  "data": 
    [1,3,5,2,6,8,4,23,7,3]
  }
}

jsonata expression:
[{
    "median" : $sort(h.data)[5],
    "larger" : h.data.($ > 5)
}]
```

https://try.jsonata.org/1x8emp3oK

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Please share your efforts and we can help. Hint: use [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) followed by [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Answer (score 0):

[Solution](https://www.stedi.com/jsonata/playground?statev2=eJxtUMtugzAQ%2FJWVRSVQt22ApI2o0p566x%2FYPljEBCTHrgxElTD%2FXhsjesnJs5rHrodS0pvR1pIgkb8%2FVvZ9Z7QfhNu53L8T0wCMtIxUsOKzGEQYwwRAcyzxgAW%2B4hH3WJT4hiUP3Mz07BPSgBMlNVQnSGoz6iFtn0NI9r5QXf8t9ddtFQThAxRwgl2kW6GahWmUMTZdBC9QrOarPHciOreceNgnpElv7LaMxqQnyDk8wh2KZyE3mqu7Ar8y0HSKolBG3M9IcESM%2F6QS9iJtJJtODdKugQjNqOvBV%2B2PvAk1ygwmiAg%2Btl%2FN2dIj91k681UaV7jS7QlHciD8D6XegL0%3D) - The key you're missing is the usage of [variables](https://docs.jsonata.org/programming#variable-binding). Also, the median of your set is `4.5`, not `5` because the count of values is even, so the median becomes an [average of two middle numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median#Finite_data_set_of_numbers).

In my solution, I calculate median, assign it to a variable using `$variable_name := <calculation>` syntax, and refer to that result further in the array filtering.

Keep in mind that if you're using variables, whole expression must be wrapped in parenthesis `( ... )`.